# Best way to get the values from dict or list for 3 different dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, plotly, plotly-dash

So, I have 3 different data frames:

`all_options = {'free': free, 'paid': paid, 'all': df}`

What is the best way to iterate over to get the values for each one?
I want to make a plot in dash. So when user will click on "free" data frame it will show him the graph with free items only?

Comment: are these dataframes have same structure?

Comment: You need to provide more context, what values are needed, what is the structure of the dataframes? Please read this: [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: yes, so all the data frames have the same columns, just different values

Answer (score 0):

it was easy as `[v.columns for k, v in all_options.items()]`

Thank you :)